# Webview not getting loaded

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, webview

I am developing Windows Store app using C# and XAML. I am using Webview in XAML as follows.

```
        <Grid x:Name="Output" Grid.Row="1">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF707070" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BlockingRect"/>
                    <ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing1" Height="50" Width="50"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="hello"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

and in code behind C# I call Webview as follows.

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            try
            {
                WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.co.in"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                hello.Text = "Caught Exception!";
            }
        }
```

But the Google or any other web page is not getting loaded using the above Webview code. I need help to load the Webview properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set Visibility from "Collapsed" to "Visible" in XAML Webview control. It is getting loaded properly.